# CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM for download

Tags: libcurl

To donwload the file i am currently using

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Read_Cb);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ReadBuffer);
curl_easy_perform(curl_handle)
```

Can CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM be used for download ? So that i can resume the next transfer from that location.
Also does it internally send range request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM` is more suitable for uploads, HTTP POST and HTTP PUT requests. You need to use `CURLOPT_RANGE` for downloads, HTTP GET and HTTP HEAD request. If you use `CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM` for downloads, it sets `Range: <From>-` HTTP header.