# Check if byte ranges are supported before downloading

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I'm downloading a file using libcurl. When the download fails I'd like to retry and continue downloading from the last written byte.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633931/curlopt-resume-from-for-download) said I should use CURLOPT_RANGE. This looks good, but according to the documentation it cannot guarantee that I actually get a range. Now I append the data to my local file and find out it's way too large because I got the full thing instead of a range.

Is there any way to check beforehand if the server supports range requests?

I already request a header to get file size, which outputs some logging showing that byte ranges are accepted:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.0
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2023 15:17:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 110294426
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Dec 2022 00:05:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "639a64e4-692f59a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I can use CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T to get the "Content-Length", but I can't find any info to retrieve the "Accept-Ranges" even though it's shown in logging. Am I overlooking a setting here?